# How do I make a rectangle rotate to face cursor?

Tags: java, applet, rotation, awt, transform

I'm hope to make a very basic game for my end of year project (going though computer science in high school) but cant find any answers as to how to make the rectangle I am drawing to face the cursor. This site has been very useful in the past but this is my first question and i hope you guys can help.

```
dir = Math.toRadians(Math.atan2(yy1,xx1)/2*Math.PI);
```

I'm presuming the either this peice of code that is the problem or,

```
g2d.rotate(dir,xx,yy);
```

This. Should I use affine transformation and if so how?

Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

public class W extends Applet implements KeyListener, MouseMotionListener {
int xx=100,yy=100,xx1,yy1,wid,hig;
String key;
Rectangle rect1;
double dir, trueing=0;

Image offImage;
Graphics offGraphics;

public void init() {
    setSize(800,600);
    addKeyListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
}

public void update(Graphics g) {
     if (offGraphics == null) {
        offImage = createImage(800,600);
        offGraphics = offImage.getGraphics();
    }

    offGraphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    offGraphics.fillRect(0,0,800,600);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)offGraphics;
    offGraphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    g2d.rotate(dir,xx,yy);

    g2d.draw(new Rectangle(xx, yy, 10, 10));

    offGraphics.setColor(getForeground());
    g.drawImage(offImage, 0, 0, this);

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    update(g);
}

public void Game(){

}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke){
    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        yy--;
        key = "u";
        System.out.println(key+xx+"-"+yy);
        repaint();
    }
    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        yy++;
        key = "d";
        System.out.println(key+xx+"-"+yy);
        repaint();
    }
    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        xx--;
        key = "l";
        System.out.println(key+xx+"-"+yy);
        repaint();
    }
    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        xx++;
        key = "r";
        System.out.println(key+xx+"-"+yy);repaint();
        repaint();
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    xx1=e.getX();
    yy1=e.getY();
    showStatus( "Mouse at (" + xx1 + "," + yy1 + ")" );
    dir = Math.toRadians(Math.atan2(yy1,xx1)/2*Math.PI);

    repaint();

}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
}
```

}

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See this answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.  If you need to support older AWT based APIs, see [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Comment: What is the problem? Does it not work? Does it work incorrectly?

Comment: Thanks ill go learn swing I think, our teacher just kinda hand out the course work, and no it doesn't work the rectangle just spins when you move the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that I think are missing from your program.

You don't reset the rotation. After you do the rotation draw the object you want to rotate then reset the rotation using the AffineTransform

```
AffineTransform reset = new AffineTransform();
reset.rotate(0,0,0);
```

Then you can apply the transform to only rotate a single object.

```
g2d.rotate(dir,xx,yy);
g2d.draw(new Rectangle(xx, yy, 10, 10));
g2d.setTransform(reset);
```

When you are calculating the angle to which the object should rotate I would recommend using:

```
xx1 = e.getX();
yy1 = e.getY();
dir = Math.toRadians(Math.atan2(yy - yy1, xx - xx1));
```

I say this mostly because I don't understand what your math was trying to accomplish.

Hope this helps.